# ayuda con script de bash

Tags: bash, script

Hola la cuestión es que necesito crear un script que haga lo siguiente: script que reciba como parámetros dos números y que devuelva la media aritmética de los UIDs que estén entre esos dos números. La cosa es que llevo esto:

```
for var in $(cut -d: -f 3 /etc/passwd)

do

while [ $var -gt $1 ] && [ $var -lt $2 ];

do


done

done
```

Y hay que resolverlo con un while. Gracias por la ayuda de antemano.

Comment: en el script tocas /etc/passwd, pero no mencionas su lógica en la explicación. ¿Podrías indicarla? Por otra parte, ¿qué te falla? Ya estás usando while. Lee [ask] para una mejor experiencia, gracias

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Si entendí bien. Puede implementar el algoritmo de media aritmética y filtrar los numeros no adecuados, tambien usando `bc` y ["Arithmetic Expansion"](https://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/arithexp.html) para operaciones matemáticas. Aqui esta mi codigo sin `while`.

```
count=0
total=0
for var in $(cut -d: -f 3 /etc/passwd); do
    if [ $var -gt $1 ] && [ $var -lt $2 ]; then
        total=$(echo $total+$var | bc )
        ((count++))
    fi
done
echo "scale=2; $total / $count" | bc
```

Comment: Gracias por el aporte pero tiene que ser con un while, ya que se trata de un ejercicio para resolver de la forma que indico. Con un if sería más fácil, pero no sería válido. Se te ocurre alguna forma de hacerlo con un while? Y que no implique bc. Gracias 